# Apache Hive on a 32-bit OS

Tags: windows-7, hadoop, cygwin, hive

Is it possible to run Hive on a 32-bit OS? I have set up Hadoop on Windows7 using Cygwin, and got the pseudo-distributed mode running. No problems here.

I installed Hive but none of the Hive queries seem to work. They just seem stuck.

I type "bin/hive" to get into the Hive prompt. None of the Hive commands seem to work after that. They just seem to be stuck (no errors thrown).

I read somewhere that Hive does not support 32-bit OSes, but I'm not sure. If yes, is there an alternative to Hive which runs on Hadoop on a 32-bit OS? Or would there be versions of Hive that are compatible with a 32-bit OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have run Hive in 32Bit OS without problem.
[Check this link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-Requirements) for minimum requirements.

You might have some configuration issues.

For you information, as for as I know, Hive runs nothing but Hadoop MapReduce Jobs. So, it's kind of layer over MapReduce jobs. If your Hadoop jobs are running perfectly, Hive should too.

Answer (score 0):

hive is not work properly on window..if you want use hive then use UBUNTU 12.04lts